# Nuxt js + Firebase Error Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

I do have the following error

> Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined

Here is my `\.nuxt\firebase\app.js` file

```js
const firebaseModule = await import(/* webpackChunkName: 'firebase-app' */'firebase/app')
const firebase = firebaseModule.default

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
const session = firebase.apps[0]

return {
  firebase,
  session
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Which Firebase version are you using ?

Comment: I am using this version    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.6.1",
                                           "firebase": "^9.0.2",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase v9 was released not so long ago, with some breaking changes as you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/zd6ffqoK_EU).

The Nuxt module did not get updated to this version as you can see in this issue: https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/573

Meanwhile, an alternative solution looks to be available with the following package versions

```json
"@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.6.1",
"firebase": "8.6.5",
```